# Open an xls file with HSSFWorkbook crash my app in run time

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi

When I do this:

```
try {
   workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(mInputFile))
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

My android project work in debug time but crash in run time.
I Use apache POI 3.9

I suspect it could because of the missing java.rmi.UnexpectedException

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? More detail on the error?

Comment: In debug time the error log give me this: E/dalvikvm(929): Could not find class 'java.rmi.UnexpectedException', referenced from method org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory.create.   But the app suceed to open the excel file.  In run time the app crashes without any exception catched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gagravarr..

As metioned on this http://poi.apache.org/changes.html link, "Avoid using RMI based exception from PropertySetFactory, as it's not needed nor helpful" is been fixed in Version 3.10-FINAL (2014-02-08).

Use, 3.10 Final or upper version to get rid of 'java.rmi.UnexpectedException' error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mistake in PropertySetFactory - there's no reason for it to be using a RMI exception, as there's no RMI involved. My hunch is that it's the RMI class that's confusing Android.

I've raised this as [bug #55901](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55901), and it's fixed as of [r1551832](http://svn.apache.org/r1551832). If you grab a nightly build from tomorrow, or do a SVN checkout and build yourself, it ought to now be fixed.